# my win10 system can not recognize 8dot3name path in websphere server

Tags: windows-10, websphere

My websphere application's path is

> C:\Projects\IBM\WCDE_ENT70,

when I start the server,the error shows it can not find the path like

> C:\Projects\IBM\WCDE_E~1\xx\.....,

I googled this name and it says it's a 8dot3name path.I ran this application in win7 and it's ok until I moved it to win10 system.
The microsoft online doc below also don't mention the 8dot3name can apply to win10,

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/ff621566(v=ws.11)

so I'm wondering does the microsoft has removed it in win10 or not.If it does,can I enable it?
I've used the cmd

> fsutil 8dot3name query

and it shows 0 which already means

> Enables 8dot3 name creation for all volumes on the system.

according to the doc.So does anybody know how to do?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I resovled this problem with this cmd:

> fsutil file setshortname "C:\Projects\IBM\WCDE_ENT70" WCDE_E~1

I don't know the reason but thanks to the friends from IBM Community:

> https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=3fab7884-ae23-4203-b992-cb73843d83a4#repliesPg=0

It may not the websphere issue,perhaps the OS.